# Conditional String Prefix in R

Tags: r, regex, string, paste

I have a data frame like this

```
X <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
            variable = c("AA", "ab", "BB", "ad", "da", "DD"))
```

I am trying to prefix a character conditionally on all the variables such that the resulting data frame is something like this(G prefixed when we have capital letters and M prefixed when we have small letters)

```
1   GAA
2   Mab
3   GBB
4   Mad
5   Mda
6   GDD
```

I tried to write a function to achieve which looks like this

```
prefix <- function(raw_data)
{
  if(raw_data$Members %like% "^[a-z]") {
    raw_data$Members = paste0('M', raw_data$Members)
  }
  else {if(raw_data$Members %like% "^[A-Z]")
  {
    raw_data$Members = paste0('G', raw_data$Members)
  }
  }
}
```

It is either prefixing only G or only M. Please help me identify what is wrong with this function or if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ifelse`, and `grepl` to check whether an element starts with a lower case letter or not.

```
ifelse(grepl("^[a-z]", X$variable), paste0("M", X$variable), paste0("G", X$variable))
#[1] "GAA" "Mab" "GBB" "Mad" "Mda" "GDD"
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if a `tolower` version of the variable equals the original, and use the result to index a vector with "G" and "M":

```
paste0(c("G", "M")[(X$variable == tolower(X$variable)) + 1], X$variable)
# [1] "GAA" "Mab" "GBB" "Mad" "Mda" "GDD"
```

Comment: This is actually faster than the solution provided by @markus. I benchmarked them with a longer version of the original data frame (using `microbenchmark`) and got roughly 2.5x speedup using this version. I guess strictly testing for equality of two strings is faster than the regex test?

Comment: @Thanks Henrik, This is also a great solution and as qdread said faster as well.

Comment: @qdread Thanks for benchmarking. Possibly a combination of no regex and no `ifelse` that contributes to the speedup.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `sub`. Probably not the best solution in this case, but it's a more general solution for "Conditional String Prefix in R".

```
X$variable <- sub('(?=^[A-Z])', 'G', X$variable, perl = T)

X$variable <- sub('(?=^[a-z])', 'M', X$variable, perl = T)

X

#   value variable
# 1     1      GAA
# 2     2      Mab
# 3     3      GBB
# 4     4      Mad
# 5     5      Mda
# 6     6      GDD
```

Tidyverse equivalent:

```
library(tidyverse)

X %>% 
  mutate_at('variable', ~ str_replace(., '(?=^[A-Z])', 'G') %>% 
                            str_replace('(?=^[a-z])', 'M'))
```